# How to rename a file that contains spaces in terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

I have a file with the name:

`this is my app.ipa`

I'd like to rename this file:

```
mv $(path)/this is my app.ipa $(path)/this_is_my_app.ipa
```

Does not seem right... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `path` a variable or a program? Variables are expanded with `${...}`, `$(...)` is for running a command and substituting its output.

Comment: `$(path)` most likely does something else than you think.  `${path}` perhaps?

Comment: `$(path)` would try to execute a command called `path` and substitute its output. There's no such command. `$PATH` or `${PATH}` are not much use either as they both refer to the command search path for your session. It might be better to make it obvious it's an example path in your example eg. `mv source_folder/this\ is\ my\ app.ipa destination_folder/this_is_my_app.ipa`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While you could precede each space with a `\` character, you would be better of enclosing the entire file name with a pair of double quotes`""`, as shown below. Here I assume `path` is  a variable, which also may contain spaces.

```
mv "$path/this is my app.ipa" "$path/this_is_my_app.ipa"
```

Or, a suppose you could also use the following.

```
mv "$path"/this\ is\ my\ app.ipa "$path"/this_is_my_app.ipa
```

If `path` is executable with output, then you are correct to use `$(path)`.

Comment: Single quotes can be useful if the filename contains `$` or other shell metacharacters: `mv "$path"/'this is my $$$ money.ipa' "$path"/'this_is_my_$$$_money.ipa'`

Answer (score 15):

[Other](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/448261/33335) [answers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/448258/33335) [explain](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/448259/33335) the various ways to enquote or escape spaces.  But as another option, **tab-completion is your friend** here and whenever you have filenames that are difficult to type — whether due to characters that need escaping, accented or otherwise unusual characters, or just length.

Specifically, if you start typing the command and current filename:

```
   mv $(path)/thi
```

and then press <kbd>tab</kbd>, your shell should automatically complete to the escaped filename:

```
   mv $(path)/this\ is\ my\ app.ipa
```

after which you can continue typing the command.  (If you have multiple files whose names begin the same way, tab-completion should complete the name as far as the first ambiguous character.)

Comment: This depends on which shell you use and how it is configured.  It is true for the default given on MacOS.

Answer (score 6):

You have to either escape the spaces:

```sh
mv $(path)/this\ is\ my\ app.ipa $(path)/this_is_my_app.ipa
```

or use quote marks:

```sh
mv "$(path)/this is my app.ipa" $(path)/this_is_my_app.ipa
```

Answer (score 5):

Depends on the shell.

Most are enclose in quotes - either " or ' - they do have different effects in expanding environment variables. POSIX shells don't expand ~
so

```
mv "$(path)/this is my app.ipa" $(path)/this_is_my_app.ipa
```

POSIX shells also allow escaping characters using \

```
mv $(path)/this\ is\ my\ app.ipa $(path)/this_is_my_app.ipa
```

Also if there is only one file with a similar name use wildcards
e.g.

```
mv $(path)/this*.ipa $(path)/this_is_my_app.ipa
```

or

```
mv $(path)/this?is?my?app.ipa $(path)/this_is_my_app.ipa
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a bit of a different approach which may be useful to you.**

This following code will rename the file "this is my app.ipa", in the current working directory, to this "this_is_my_app.ipa"

```
for f in ./"this is my app.ipa" ;do echo "$f" |mv "$f" "$(sed 's@ @_@g')" ;done
```

This following version will rename all files, in the current working directory, ending with ".ipa" which also contain spaces in the name... by replacing blank spaces with underscores.

```
for f in ./*.ipa ;do echo "$f" |mv "$f" "$(sed 's@ @_@g')" ;done
```

This following version will rename all files, in the current working directory, which contain spaces in the name... by replacing blank spaces with underscores.

```
for f in ./* ;do echo "$f" |mv "$f" "$(sed 's@ @_@g')" ;done
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could type `mv` and a space then drag and drop the file into the terminal, it will add the full path of the file all properly escaped (and then you type another space and the new name)

Or you could copy the path, then type `mv` and a space then <kbd>⌃</kbd>-<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> (or in the menu: Edit → Paste Escaped Text) and another space and the new name.

Answer (score -2):

Use quotation marks when specifying long filenames or paths with spaces. For example, typing the copy c:\my file name d:\my new file name command at the command prompt results in the following error message: The system cannot find the file specified. The quotation marks must be used.

Regards,
Peter

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Your answer would be a little more credible if your example actually used a Unix file naming convention rather than Windows / MS-DOS commands and conventions. I'd advise you make an amendment to bring it into line with what's generally accepted here.

Comment: But neither does this add anything that isn't already covered by the existing answers.